# How to do an infinite loop with jquery queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue

The code I have flips 6 tiles after the page is loaded.
This works fine.

```
var flipTiles = function() {
    $('.flip-tile').each(function( i, el ) {
        var elDelay = $(el).data('delay');
        $(el).delay(elDelay).queue(function() {
            $(this).flip(true);
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    });
};

flipTiles();
```

My question is how could I make this so the tiles keep flipping. Like there page loads and the tiles flip with there own delay. After all tiles flipped I wanna restart the sequence and flip them back etc.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to unwrap the loop and make each step trigger the next in sequence, see comments:

```
var flipTiles = function() {
    // Grab the tiles
    var tiles = $('.flip-tile');
    // Start with the first tile
    var i = 0;
    // Do that tile
    next();
    function next() {
        var tile = tiles.eq(i);
        tile.delay(tile.data('delay')).queue(function() {
            tile.flip(true);
            tile.dequeue();
            // Increment `i`, wrap-around at the end
            i = (i + 1) % tiles.length;
            // Do the next tile
            next();
        });
    }
};

flipTiles();
```

If you want to make it possible to cancel it, return something the caller can use to do that:

```
var flipTiles = function() {
    var running = true;
    // Grab the tiles
    var tiles = $('.flip-tile');
    // Start with the first tile
    var i = 0;
    // Do that tile
    next();
    // Return something the caller can use to cancel
    return function() {
        running = false;
    };
    function next() {
        if (!running) {
            return;
        }
        var tile = tiles.eq(i);
        tile.delay(tile.data('delay')).queue(function() {
            tile.flip(true);
            tile.dequeue();
            // Increment `i`, wrap-around at the end
            i = (i + 1) % tiles.length;
            // Do the next tile
            next();
        });
    }
};

var cancel = flipTiles();
// (later)
cancel();
```

Comment: This will not work, because you will enter the function `next` and never leave it.

Comment: @DaniloKörber- No, you won't. Try it! `next` returns almost immediately, having scheduled some asynchronous callbacks, and then `flipTiles` returns almost immediately. The tiles keep flipping as the asynchronous callbacks get called by the browser's timer mechanism.

Comment: @t-j-crowder - I tried it and the code never leaves the function `next`... https://jsfiddle.net/dkorber/52uabqn9/6/

Comment: @DaniloKörber - The code in that fiddle is missing the critical aspect I called out in my comment above: Scheduling asynchronous callbacks. You've just completely discarded the relevant bit. I suggest you review [`delay`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [`queue`](https://api.jquery.com/queue/).

Answer (score 0):

To "loop forever" you can use the `setTimeout` event:

```
myVar = setTimeout(function() { flipTiles(); }, 3000); // 3000 is the value in milliseconds to repeat the command
```

to stop the "loop" use

```
clearTimeout(myVar);
```

Comment: This won't work for two reasons. Firstly because you're providing the *response* of the `flipTiles()` function to `setTimeout()`, not the function *reference*. Secondly because you're telling it to flip 6 cards every 3 seconds, not flip them infinitely at a specific interval

Comment: Thanks, @rory-mcgrossan. I corrected the code that calls the function. The three seconds are only an example, he has to adjust it to his needs.